# What is the FOC of this lagrangian with respect to $I$?

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Consider the following maximization problem:
$$ \max_{x,I}G(x,y) $$ subject to the constraints $$ p_x x +p_I I= z \\ y=f(I, q)\\ q=q^0$$

---

Here is my attempt at writing out the lagrangian
$$ \Lambda = G(x,y) - \lambda_1 (p_x x + p_I I - z) - \lambda_2 (y-f(I,q)-\lambda_3 (q-q^0)$$
**Is the First order condition with respect to $I$:**
$$
\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial I} - \lambda_1 p_I - \lambda_2 (\frac{\partial y}{\partial I} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial I})=0$$
or is it
$$- \lambda_1 p_I - \lambda_2  \frac{\partial f}{\partial I}=0$$

> In other words, when I take the partial of the lagrange with respect
> to $I$, do I treat $y$ as a constant, or as a function of $I$?

- (I get confused because we don't choose $y$ directly, so it is more like a parameter than a variable, but we have a constraint that says $y$ depends on $I$